# How to deserialize Json string to a dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string that has dynamic fields, as below

```
"errors": {
    "StartTime, StopTime": [
      "lorem ipsum","doh rey mee far so lar ti doo","this is an error"
    ], 
        "SetupMinutes": [
      "Insufficient time until StartTime to allow for SetupMinutes",
      "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    ],
    "Another field with an error" : [
      "This field is bad", "this field is bad too", "all fields are bad"
    ],
    "propX":["this is another field","this is another item"],
    "propY":["this is another field","this is another item"]
```

All the child fields of "errors" are dynamic.

How can I deserialize this into a dynamic JSON object?

Comment: How do you plan to make any kind of order out of chaos?  Really, you should structure your errors better, then it's easy to deserialize.

Comment: What have you tried?  And how did it not provide the result you expect?  We need to see your attempt, so please edit your question and provide your code segment.

Comment: You do realize that what you have shown isn't valid json?

Comment: `JToken` itself is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the dictionary is the best for the dynamic fields

```
Dictionary<string,string[]> errors = JObject.Parse(json)["errors"].ToObject<Dictionary<string,string[]>>();
```

how to use

```
string startStopTime = string.Join(",",errors["StartTime, StopTime"]);

//result
"lorem ipsum,doh rey mee far so lar ti doo,this is an error"
```